# What does this following expression mean?

Tags: image-processing, bitwise-operators, xor, typecast-operator, leptonica

This expression is taken from an inbuilt function "l_setDataByte" in Leptonica(an Image-Processing library).

Here is the link: http://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/arrayaccess_8c_source.html (Line-260 here)

```
*(l_uint8 *)((l_uintptr_t)((l_uint8 *)line + n) ^ 3) = val;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

- line is a pointer to unsigned 8bits (byte) `(l_uint8 *)line`
- one manipulates the n-th byte in the line:  `(l_uint8 *)line + n`  --> y (y is a pointer)
- however one also XORs the last 2 bits of the address after casting as an unsinged integer pointer: `(l_uintptr_t)y ^ 3` --> z (z is a pointer)
- lastly one casts back to a unsigned byte points and writes the value `val` there: `*(l_uint8 *)z = val`

**Edit**:
The ^3 is to address the arrangement of the bytes (i.e. little vs big endian). The number 0x12345678 can be put in consecutive bytes in two ways: 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 (this is big endian) or 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12 (little endian). The XOR will switch from big endian addressing (see line 274) to little endian (line 276). This is processor dependent and the source is compiled one way or the other.

Comment: What happens if we xor the last two bits of an address ?

I know ...11 becomes ...00, ...10 becomes ...01, ...01 becomes ...10 and ...00 becomes ...11

But, why is he doing that ?